# Determine arbitrary latest day in a month via TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

In each row of data I'm working with, I have a date, and a value:

```
f1                            f2 
2012-01-01 00:00:00.000       10
2012-01-10 00:00:00.000       9
2012-02-01 00:00:00.000       19
2012-02-15 00:00:00.000       31
```

Using TSQL, I need to return each row which contains the latest DAY for specific year-month combinations - For example, in the data above, I need to return the second and fourth rows since 1/10/2012 carries the "latest" day stored for Jan-2012, and 2/15/2012 is the latest day recorded in Feb-2012. Desired results:

```
f1                            f2 
2012-01-10 00:00:00.000       9
2012-02-15 00:00:00.000       31
```

Note that this isn't as simple as simply determining the "last day of the month" or "last business day of the month".

I suspect I need to use some sort of combination of GROUP BY, HAVING which includes a MAX on datepart("day", f1), but I'm at a loss on how to move forward. Can someone push me in the right direction?

Comment: Please specify which version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: Do you ever have more than one row in your source on a given date?

Comment: @JohnDewey makes a good point - if rows 3 and 4 both have the same date, how do you want to break the tie? You need to tell SQL Server which row you want, even if you don't care, otherwise you could have different results each time you run the query.

Comment: Gents, I've given you an simplified version of the schema - in the real world, there be another field (let's call it a customer ID) which will unique-ify the dates. So for each CustomerID, we'll only see a date appear once. As long as we're grouping on CustomerID, no ties to worry about.

Comment: Aaron - gulp...SQL 2000. Don't laugh...Well, laugh a little, but be kind :)

Comment: Trust me, I'm not laughing. Please have the courtesy to specify your SQL Server version up front, especially when using an ancient version that is no longer supported and definitely not assumed to be the version in use, so poor saps like me don't waste time crafting a solution you can't use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes, as pointed out by others, that the values for f1 are distinct within your set.

```
SELECT
    MaxValues.f1,
    Detail.f2
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        DATEPART(year, f1),
        DATEPART(month, f1),
        MAX(f1) AS f1
    FROM
        MyTable
    GROUP BY
        DATEPART(year, f1),
        DATEPART(month, f1)
    ) AS MaxValues
    INNER JOIN MyTable AS Detail ON
        Detail.f1 = MaxValues.f1
```

Comment: I think this will work nicely, as the guy I'm working with is still running on 2K...As I recall, 2000 does support nested subqueries like this.

Comment: @RussellChristopher - I believe on later versions this might get optimised to remove the JOIN as well.

Comment: @RussellChristopher thanks for accepting. As an aside, I took your comment about "will work nicely" and "as the guy...is still running on 2K" as an implication that perhaps this is some kind of deprecated feature. It's a vanilla derived table, and most RDBMSs support that. It's the weak ones that don't. This syntax works in MSSQL Server since I can remember, which is a long time. Not only does it work in 2000, but also 2005, 2008 and 2008 R2. It is also not nested.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming SQL Server 2005 or better:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (f1 DATETIME, f2 INT);

INSERT @t SELECT '2012-01-01',10
UNION ALL SELECT '2012-01-10',9
UNION ALL SELECT '2012-02-01',19
UNION ALL SELECT '2012-02-15',31;

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT f1, f2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
   PARTITION BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, f1), 0) 
   ORDER BY f1 DESC) AS rn
  FROM @t
)
SELECT f1, f2 FROM x
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: PARTITION BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, f1), 0)... could have been reduced to PARTITION BY DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, f1))..., still it is the right idea +1

Comment: @t-clausen.dk it's a good point, I get in the habit of including both after too many times having to answer why I was only grouping on an integer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Or less

```
SELECT f1, f2 
FROM (SELECT f1, f2, MAX(f1) OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(f1), MONTH(f1)) AS f3 FROM @t) t
WHERE f1 = f3
```